# Can't connect my swift app to node.js via socket.io

Tags: node.js, swift, socket.io

I need to connect my iOS app (**swift**) to the **node.js** server via **socket.io**. I followed the [socket.io official tutorial](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/), but I'm still stuck.

I'm try to connect to the server and simply emit "authentification", but I don't receive any feedback after the emit.

My swift code

```
class Socket{
    var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "localhost:8000", options:[.Log(true), .ForcePolling(true)])

    init(){
            self.addHandles()
            self.socket.connect()
            socket.connect()
            self.socket.emit("authentification","gaamy#test") 
    }

    func addHandles(){
        self.socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
            print(data)
        }

        self.socket.on("error") {data in
            print("socket ERROR")
            print(data)
        }

        self.socket.on("reponse connection") {data in
            print("reponse connection")
            print(data)
        }  
        self.socket.onAny {
           print("Got event: \($0.event), with items: \($0.items!)")
        }

    }
}
```

The node.js socket.on:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('authentification', function(info) {
    var res = info.split("#");
    var username = res[0];
    var password = res[1];
    userModel.findOne({'username':username}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('reponse connection', 'false#Impossible de se connecter a la base de données');
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).disconnect();
        }
        else if(!user){
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('reponse connection', "false#Nom d'utilisateur invalide");
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).disconnect();
        }
        else if (user.password == password){
            var stringUsers = username;
            for(var clef of userMap.keys()){
                stringUsers = stringUsers + '+' + clef;
            }
            // pour eviter le doublon de username
            if(typeof(userMap.get(username))==="undefined")
            {
                userMap.set(username, socket.id);
                io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('reponse connection', 'true#' + stringUsers);
                socket.broadcast.emit("userConnected",username);
                socket.broadcast.emit("message", username+" Is Now Connected!");
                socket.username = username;
                socket.host = 0;
                console.log(username,' Is Now Connected!');
            }
            else{
                io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('reponse connection', "false#Nom d'utilisateur invalide");
                io.sockets.socket(socket.id).disconnect();
            }
        }
        else{
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('reponse connection', 'false#Mot de pass invalide');
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).disconnect();
        }   
    });
  });
```

There is the Xcode output:

```
2015-12-03 13:03:21.267 Projet3[26084:369975] Log SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: reponse connection
2015-12-03 13:03:21.268 Projet3[26084:369975] Log SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: error
2015-12-03 13:03:21.268 Projet3[26084:369975] Log SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: connect
2015-12-03 13:03:21.269 Projet3[26084:369975] Log SocketIOClient: Adding engine
2015-12-03 13:03:21.271 Projet3[26084:369975] Log SocketEngine: Starting engine
2015-12-03 13:03:21.271 Projet3[26084:369975] Log SocketEngine: Handshaking
2015-12-03 13:03:21.272 Projet3[26084:369975] Log SocketEngine: Doing polling request
2015-12-03 13:03:21.399 Projet3[26084:370051] Log SocketEngine: Got polling response
2015-12-03 13:03:21.400 Projet3[26084:370051] Log SocketEngine: Got message: Welcome to socket.io.
```

This "***Welcome to socket.io.***" means I am connected to the server?

Comment: I just realized that the socket.io on the server side is on version 0.9. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that my server is running socket.io v0.9 and [socket.io-client-swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) suports socket.io v1.0+.

I couldn't just update my server because an other client are running C# and using [socketio4net](https://github.com/jstott/socketio4net/tree/develop) which is compatible only with socket.io v0.9.

The solution is to use [socket.IO-objc](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) because it suports socket.io v0.9.

**Step 1:** 
Get socket.IO-objc [here](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc/releases).

**Step 2:** 
Import socket.IO-objc in your project.
Useful post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/4220809

**Step 3:** 
Install dependencies (SocketRocket).
Use cocoapods to import this objective-c library in my swift project.
Tutorial: [Using Objective-C CocoaPods libraries with Swift](http://tsigo.github.io/blog/2014/11/06/using-objective-c-cocoapods-libraries-with-swift/)

Comment: Hi, where did you find the tutorial to connect these stack? I'm trying to connect MySQL, Node.js and SwiftUI